# Why the data is not loaded if using Form_Shown event?

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, data-binding, datagrid

I'm working on WinForms application with DataGrid control. I have used BindingSource as datasource and i have initialized the **BindingSource.DataSource** in **Form_Shown** event. The parent table is loaded correctly but child table is not loaded. ***If I initialize the BindingSource.DataSource in Form_Load event, it working fine, there is no issues.***

Why this kind difference happens with using BindingSource in Form_Shown and Form_Load events?

Please let me know the reason.
`

```
 Form1.Designer.vb
 Me.DataGridView.DataSource = Me.BindingSource1
```

Form1.vb

```
Private Sub Form1_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
    ''Does not work
    BindingSource1.DataSource = ParentList.FetchMaintenance
    ''Does work
    DataGridView.DataSource = ParentList.FetchMaintenance
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

According to MSDN:

> Form_Load or Load events occurs before the form will be displayed for
>   the first time.

While

> The Shown event is only raised the first time a form is displayed.

Maybe because the form didn't load your Binding Source that's why it didn't load on the Shown event. Because there is none to show.